# Adding text in front of each row in 2d arrays

Tags: python

I have a 2d array, which  I print on screen with something like

```
matrix= [[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]

print '\hline\n'''.join([' & \t'.join([str(x[i]) if len(x) > i else ' ' for x in matrix]) for i in range(len(max(matrix)))])
```

so it looks like

```
1 & 2 & 3 \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \hline
```

however, I fail to find a way to insert at (0) from another list

```
cuts = ('row one', 'row two')
```

so to look like

```
row one & 1 & 2 & 3 \hline
row two & 4 & 5 & 6 \hline
```

TIA

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Please include the original data structure that employs the given conditions and comprehension.

Comment: I really don't see why people rush to downvote posts without really been of any help

Comment: If this is a recurring problem for you, I suggest that you re-take the intro tour.  Pay special attention to the long-term purpose of the site.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Note that, once you completed your post, I removed my down-vote and you had at least two of us typing to help you.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but fwiw I agree with Prune. That code doesn't produce that output (it's missing the second `\hline`), and the print line seems to be overly complex. A [mre] will really help in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to do everything in one line with multiple advanced Python stuff, you can write more straight forward code:

```
matrix = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
cuts = ('row one', 'row two')
lines = [' & \t'.join([str(x[i]) if len(x) > i else ' ' for x in matrix]) for i in range(len(max(matrix)))]
for i in range(len(cuts)):
    print('{} & {} \hline\n'''.format(cuts[i], lines[i]), end="")
```

Comment: You beat me by almost a full minute!  :-)

Comment: although I am not using python3, I can make it work by removing the end from the end